# How to NOT refresh backgroundQuery vba

Tags: vba, excel, web, refresh

Does anyone know how to stop the refresh query table to constantly refreshing and only refresh itself once. he constant refresh, is making my excel spreadsheet run slow.

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;" & FilePath, _
       Destination:=temp.Range("A1"))
   .Name = "Deloitte_2013_08"
    '    .CommandType = 0
       .FieldNames = True
       .RowNumbers = False
      .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
     .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
   .BackgroundQuery = True
  .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
 .SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
  .RefreshPeriod = 0
      .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
     .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
   .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
  .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
 .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
.WebDisableRedirections = False

       .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

```
.BackgroundQuery = True
```

to:

```
.BackgroundQuery = False
```

Comment: Woops. I definitely misread this question :) +1 for the best answer. Mine will be useful but not do this.

Comment: @enderland, I hate it when that happens :). But at least we have two smiley gravatars.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Application.ScreenUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb221605%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to wrap your code.

```
application.screenupdating = false
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;" & FilePath, _
       Destination:=temp.Range("A1"))
   .Name = "Deloitte_2013_08"
    '    .CommandType = 0
       .FieldNames = True
       .RowNumbers = False
      .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
     .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
   .BackgroundQuery = True
  .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
 .SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
  .RefreshPeriod = 0
      .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
     .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
   .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
  .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
 .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
.WebDisableRedirections = False

       .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With

application.screenupdating = true
```

You might also be interested in setting [Application.Calculation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb212499%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to `xlCalculationManual` before a large operation and then setting it to `xlCalculationAutomatic` after you are done.